# Switching std::priority_queue comparator after construction

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am implementing a [median cut algorithm](http://leptonica.org/papers/mediancut.pdf) which uses a priority queue to track which box to split next:

- The first 50% cuts will be done based on `population`
- The remaining 50% cuts will be done based on `population * volume`.

I am using a `std::priority_queue`, which looks something like that for step 1:

```
auto compareVBoxPopulation = [](const VBox &a, const VBox &b) {
  return a.population < b.population;
};

auto compareVBoxPopulationAndVolume = [](const VBox &a, const VBox &b) {
  return (a.population * a.volume) < (b.population * b.volume);
};

std::priority_queue<VBox, std::vector<VBox>, decltype(compareVBoxPopulation)>
      queue(compareVBoxPopulation);

// do some cuts
// change comparator to compareVBoxPopulationAndVolume
// do some more cuts
```

I would like to change the comparator of my `std::priority_queue` from `compareVBoxPopulation` to `compareVBoxPopulationAndVolume`. I could just create another `std::priority_queue`, but I would like to reuse the content of the underlying `vector<VBox>`.

There are [a bunch of constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) that take a container, but I can't access the `vector` of my `std::priority_queue` as it is protected. Ideally, I'd need something like

```
priority_queue(const Compare& compare, priority_queue&& other);
```

Here both comparators have the same type, so it could technically work. Is there a way to get this behavior?

Comment: The ordering of the elements in a `std::priority_queue` is done only on insertion of elements. Attempting to change comparator for a non-empty priority queue will not affect the elements already in it.

Comment: `std::vector`, `std::make_heap`.

Comment: So I would ditch the `std::priority_queue` altogether and just use a `std::vector`, calling `push_back` + `make_heap` rather than `push`, and `top` would become `front`, etc.? Would performance suffer? Is `std::priority_queue` doing more stuff in the background?

Comment: I just realized there a bunch of functions like `push_heap`, and `pop_heap` already in the standard.  Would I get similar performance compared to `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: @Touloudou The performance would be the same. The main benefit of `priority_queue` is to provide a higher-level interface and that you avoid the bugs you get from managing the heap by hand.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok. I gave it a try, and performance is indeed the same. Note however that I had to use variadic templates for my comparators. The alternative would have been `std::function`, but that did not feel like a good fit for this performance-sensitive part of the code.

Comment: Your two comparators do *not* have the same type (although they would if you decayed them to function pointers).

Comment: @DavisHerring If I use variadic templates and store my comparators in a `tuple`, the compiler should be able to inline the function call, right?

Comment: @Touloudou: It’s hard to be sure from just a description, but generally non-decayed lambdas do inline very well.